# Android Orientation issue, no scrolling

Tags: android, keyboard, scroll, hardware, tabs

I am using Eclipse and developed an app that has 3 tabs using Android 1.5.  The program works just fine.
1st problem--whenever the app is run, it change orientations, but does not show the scroll bars, thus allowing to scroll down(or up).  Is this suppose to be happening?  And how is it corrected?

2nd problem--if you are on say tab2, then open or close the key board (T-Mobile G1), the tab2 switches to tab1.  No matter if you are one tab1 or tab2, opening/closing the keyboard will switch it back to tab1.  Does anyone know what the fix is?

Comment: Side note: next time please try two create two separate questions instead of one big. That raises chances to get answer faster and help community to distinguish problems better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Investigate usage of ScrollView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html
2. I guess on keyboard open/close your activity is recreated (not sure though), try saving your tabs state (e.g. index of selected tab) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) and restoring it during onCreate.